# Ireboot doesn't recognize the other Windows from the other SSD

Tags: windows

I'm tired to enter the bios each time I want to switch from my SSD with Windows 10 to my SSD with Windows 7.

I had a mac with bootcamp, I used it to switch from mac to windows or the other way while being in the operating system.

In other words, I want to do a few click while I'm using Windows 10 on The priority no 1 hard drive(ssd in my case, it doesnt really matter). Leave the room while the computer shut down and restart in windows 7 on another hard drive.

- I have already installed windows 7 and 10 using real licenses on 2 different hard drive.

Thanks for help

Ireboot, Ive installed it in my windows 7 also, same problem.
Windows 7 missing:

[image]

[image]

iReboot still doesn't recognize the other windows installation

I tried to fix it
[image]

I cannot boot in windows 10 anymore...
[image]

[image]

Fixed but iReboot still doesnt show my windows 7

Comment: Use Advanced Startup to change the boot order on your devices.

Comment: I like this utility....https://neosmart.net/iReboot/

Comment: Skip the email leech, just click Download.

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe read more than the title.

Comment: @Moab iReboot doesnt really work, maybe you know a fix.

Comment: Works for me, not sure what your issue is.

Comment: Are you using iReboot version 2.0.1? It seems to me that you have used diskpart to wipeout one disk, so what have you done to fill back the empty disk?

Comment: @harrymc I've downloaded iRevoot from the website, so it's the most recent version. "what have you done to fill back the empty disk" It was another disk, I've installed windows 10 on it but I didn't needed it there so I cleaned it.

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall iReboot and reboot ?

Comment: @harrymc yes I did, I did much more than that.

Comment: This might be a bug in iReboot, better discussed on their [forums](https://neosmart.net/forums/). A commercial alternative might be [BootIt Bare Metal](http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/bootit-bare-metal.htm) ($39.95 with trial) and its Direct Boot Menu.

Comment: @harrymc interesting. Right now I have issues with my bcd. I can't boot on windows 7 anymore, I'll take a look at this alternative if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your Windows installations are unaware of each other - you have bootloaders and EFI partitions installed on both drives. It happens eg. when you're installing Windows with other hard disks disconnected. That makes drive bootable independently from other ones, but also creates this problem: you have two boot configurations that have to be managed separately.

You will probably have to apply the fix to both drives. Try it on first drive, then try rebooting to both systems. If the other one still doesn't know about first one, then switch master drive, boot the other OS and repeat.

You can fix this either with command-line tool `bootrec` (not really user-friendly, but no 3rd party software required) or with [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) (GUI-based, user-friendly).

#### Using EasyBCD

1. On *BCD Backup/Repair* tab: Backup your current BCD settings.
2. On *Add New Entry* tab: Select other OS's version, enter label to use for it and select drive letter. Click *Add Entry*.

(You don't actually have to install EasyBCD in both OSes - if applying fix on just one isn't sufficient, you can use *File → Select BCD store* and load BCD store from the other drive.)

#### Using `bootrec`

1. Boot from Windows DVD (or flash drive prepared with [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10)).
2. Click *Repair computer → [select Windows instance] → System Recovery Options → Command Prompt*.
3. Backup your BCD store: Type `bcdedit /export C:\Path\where\you\want\to\export` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Add all Windows instances to BCD store: Type `bootrec /scanos` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

More info on `bootrec` can be found in [Microsoft's article on using it](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392).

Comment: iReboot still doesn't recognize the other windows installation, photo added. EasyBCD is not free

Comment: @Mark It's free for personal use, you have to register to download it. Have you done `bootrec /scanos` for both disks? Maybe iReboot is using the wrong one...

Comment: Well check the picture I've uploaded. One of the ssd in on a pcie slot, does it change something?

Comment: That shouldn't matter. The screenshot only shows that bootrec detected two Windows installations, that's good - but my suspicion is that you have two BCD stores. Bootrec added second entry to one store only and you have to repeat it for the other one. Oh, do you maybe know if you're booting through EFI or legacy boot/BIOS?

Comment: Well, I've done it with my usb key from my retail purchase, but the other windows 7 comes from a ghost(OEM WIndows 7 laptop hhd to samsung evo ssd). I should get a win 7 cd(I have some) and do the bootrec again?

Comment: I think it will work with that USB key. Try switching to the other disk like you normally would to boot Windows 7 and boot from USB. This time select Windows 7 (it should show both and let you pick before you can access command line). Be careful not to overwrite your previous BCD backup.

Comment: But to access this repair menu I boot on the usb key(win10), and then I don't know what I can do next to select the windows 7 drive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43919/discussion-between-gronostaj-and-mark).

Comment: I just found out that the backup I've done has been saved on the wrong ssd

Comment: There must be a way to select drive, do you know

Comment: Becaus I've installed windows 10 on that other ssd but finally I didnt needed windows 10 there so I've formated it after. Don't worry I'm not crazy, I tried to fix my relatively slow startup 45 seconds caused by my pcie ssd and my motherboard x99

Comment: I dont know actually I have some bootsqm.dat, I dont really understand.